# how to reflect changes in cache when using mutations in react rest-hooks library in suitable way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest-hooks

I want to add new endpoint to my resource which will return total number of rows in database. I am struggling with changes reflection  after basic CRUD like create() or  delete() in a DRY way using normalized cache.

I am aware about updateParams in useFetcher hooks, it does not suite for my use case due to the fact that i will have multiple entities that are using this enpoint. it will force me to write every mutation with updateParams with the same code.

Answer (score 1):

https://resthooks.io/docs/guides/immediate-updates has been updated to include information about how to use [Endpoint.update](https://resthooks.io/docs/api/Endpoint#update) in a reusable manner